# Cumulative number of entries in dates range

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-line-chart

I'm trying to get cumulative number of unique IDs in given timeframe.
My DAX look like this:

```
Cumulative = CALCULATE(SUM(Data[ID]));DATESBETWEEN(Data[ack_date];DATE(YEAR(NOW());4;1);DATE(YEAR(NOW());11;30)))
```

There is similar measure for Year-1: [YEAR(NOW())-1]

What I want to achieve is area chart showing growing number od IDs in time comparing same periods this and previous year. When I give those measures as Values for chart and "ack_date" as its Axis what I get is values comparison month by month but not cumulative, just value for certain month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Adjust for year -1.

```
=
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[ID] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Data ),
        AND (
            Data[Ack_date] <= MAX ( Data[Ack_date] ),
            AND (
                Data[Ack_date] <= DATE ( YEAR ( NOW () ), 11, 30 ),
                Data[Ack_date] >= DATE ( YEAR ( NOW () ), 4, 1 )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, It's working for current year, but when I do the same for year-1 something is wrong - it returns one same number for whole year even if I want just April - November perion in filter. The original code is below:
Y-1 Kandydaci cumulative = CALCULATE(
 DISTINCTCOUNT(getDataForTeb[ID_DANE_OSOBOWE]);
 FILTER(
  ALL (getDataForTeb);
  AND (
   getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania] <= MAX(getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania]);
   AND (
    getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania] <= DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1; 11; 30);
    getDataForTeb[Złożenie podania] >= DATE(YEAR(NOW())-1; 4; 1)
   )
  )
 )
)

Comment: Screenshot here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0jxa4KoR46fekNGTVg0T1dRT00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try this formula. Please note that I haven't tested it yet...=CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[ID] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Data ),
        AND (
            Data[Ack_date] <= MAX ( Data[Ack_date] )-365,
            AND (
                Data[Ack_date] <= DATE ( YEAR ( NOW ())-1, 11, 30 ),
                Data[Ack_date] >= DATE ( YEAR ( NOW ())-1, 4, 1 )
            )
        )
    )
)

Comment: It looks like it's working. I just need to crosscheck if the numbers are reliable. Thank You again.